# Gradle Error while creating new project with Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I just installed Google Android Studio which is introduced in Google IO 2013 and going to crate new Android Project with proper dependencies.

But after pressing finish , I got a pop-up where GoogleAndroidStudio downloading Gradle to automate the build. Got error downloading Gradle and want to know how to install/Config Gradle manually , or else another way to use GAS better , please .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Gradle from the official link: http://www.gradle.org/downloads

And then you set the unpacked zip as Gradle home when you're importing your project

Comment: trying your answer. Will inform you whether I am ok with your answer or not . Thanks for your time .

Comment: Is ok for Gradle problem now with your answer . Now downloading more :) .

Answer (score 1):

Check your internet connection.that's all.When first time starting the new project, that error occurred for me.